# Can the derivative of a spherical curve be calculated in this way?

Tags: geometry

$$β=arctan [ (1+tan^2 \theta ) K\sin \alpha + tan \theta  \sqrt {1+(1+tan^2 \theta )K^2 \sin^2 \alpha}  ]$$

This is the general straight line (circle) equation on the sphere. $\alpha$ is longitude, $\beta$ is latitudes, $K$ is the slope of a straight line (circle) and $\theta $ is the distance between the point of the straight line and the equator  when alpha equals zero.

[diagram](https://sphericalparallelism.quora.com/The-general-straight-line-great-circle-and-small-circle-equation-on-the-sphere?share=e060d26c&srid=5i3fQ)

Diagram, the horizontal line (circle) is the equator, and its $K=0$. The $K$ values of other lines (circles) are $-0.3$, and their $\theta $ values are $0.45pi, \ 0.25pi, \ 0, \ 0.$

The calculation formula of the slope of the spherical curve is:

$$K={\sinβ_2-\sinβ_1\over\sinα_2\cosβ_2-\sinα_1\cosβ_1}$$

In the sphere very small area, this formula is approximate to the formula of the slope of the plane curve. So the slope of a plane curve is only a special case of the slope of a spherical curve.

**According to this formula, we can find the derivative of the spherical curve and the calculus operation for the sphere.**

Reference
https://sphericalparallelism.quora.com/When-the-diameter-of-the-sphere-tends-to-infinity-what-does-the-small-circle-tend-to?share=ce851a1c&srid=5i3fQ

Comment: Definitions and terminology can be improved.

Comment: @Narasimham Do you mean I want to improve?

Comment: I find a bit confusing. About the reference link, great circles have zero *slip* (geodesics ) which is rate of chage of opening radius ( $r_o$ Clairaut's constant) with respect to axial distance  z  of  For small circles slip $ \tan \gamma= d r_o/d z,\, \gamma$ is angle between sphere normal and local arc normal without sphere from Frenet Serret relations.

Comment: @Narasimham The link is to say that the curvature of a small circle is equal to zero. Because the slope of the latitudinal circle equals zero.

Comment: I am not able to understand this statement. Small circles have geodesic curvature $ \kappa_g\ne 0$ , great circle geodesics have it vanish. Did you mean torsion of small circle in space $=0$  without reference to sphere?

Comment: @Narasimham Let's first understand the latitude circle, and the increment in the latitude circle equals zero, so the slope of the latitude circle equals zero. So the curvature of the latitudinal circle equals zero. Right?

Comment: @Narasimham The discussion is not allowed here, and it is suggested to be discussed in the link in the article.

Comment: You mean slope of the projection of the plane of inclination in the meridional plane? Yes, it is constant and makes $ \angle \alpha =0$ for parallel circles with respect to equitorial plane.

Comment: @Narasimham I mean, when the longitude is incremental, the increase in latitude is zero, so the slope of the latitude circle is zero and the curvature is zero.

Comment: The geodesic curvature $ \kappa_g = \psi^{'} + \frac{\sin \psi \, \sin \phi }{r} $ to vanish not only $\psi^{'}=0$ but also must $\phi =0 $ . Bit of differential geometry is needed here. With pure geometry perhaps you cannot go further. We could chat much later but inside your blog only.

Comment: @Narasimham The increase in the equator is zero, so the curvature of the geodesic is zero on the sphere.

Comment: This logic to me appears incorrect. The increase in the equator as well as parallel circle or equator is zero, The geodesic curvature of the geodesic is zero **BUT** the curvature of the non-geodesic parallel circle is non-zero.

Comment: @Narasimham The slope of the latitude circle is zero, so the curvature of the latitude circle can only be zero according to the definition of curvature.

Comment: That is where you are stuck, to me appears. Bye.

Comment: @Narasimham Is there a mistake in my concept?

Comment: @Narasimham https://sphericalparallelism.quora.com/When-the-diameter-of-the-sphere-tends-to-infinity-what-does-the-small-circle-tend-to?share=ce851a1c&srid=5i3fQ

Answer (score 0):

You could correlate with the following result that has a slightly different notation ($\varphi$ latitude,  $\theta $ longitude, $ \psi $ angle small circle makes to longitude, $\alpha $ inclination of small circle to plane of equator).

$$ \tan \alpha = \dfrac{\sin \theta \cos \varphi + \cos \theta \tan \psi}{ \sin \varphi}{} $$

Comment: $$\phi =arctan ( (1+tan^2 ψ ) \tan \alpha \sin \theta + tan ψ  \sqrt {1+(1+tan^2  ψ ) \tan \alpha^2 \sin^2 \theta} )
$$Is that what it means?

Comment: You brought in a new $\phi$ without defining it.  Maybe you get better help with your derivation, not just the end result.

Comment: phi is latitudes.

Comment: What does your formula mean, I don't understand.?